# Google Cloud Datastore API Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I have managed to import a version of the Google Cloud Datastore API in my project on Eclipse using Google Plugin Tool, yeah I know it is not a great achievement!

But now what do I do....???

I can not find any correct functions for this API, either the functions are not resolved, or in other cases the imports are not resolved...

I am just trying to find a way to store some data on the Google Cloud. I am looking for just a few lines of Java code, something along the lines:

```
 import com.blah.blahblah
 . 
 .
 .
 main{
 Datastore mydata;
 mydata.put("Name", "myName"); }
```

Sort of thing. From all my reading for the past few days, it seems there are a couple of different APIs and I am using the wrong function names with the wrong API and I can't figure out how to match up the two...please some help as I am getting : (((

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is store data on the Google cloud, you have a few options. the datastore, the blobstore, CloudSQL and the Cloud Storage. Each has its own unique strengths.
Seems to me what you are looking for is a way to get started with an API, and I would recommend starting with this example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction

Comment: that example uses the appengine datastore, as far as I can tell, I am not building an appengine application, I need an API that gives me access to storage outside of the appengine system, namely through an android app...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Cloud Java client libraries:

```
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.KeyFactory;

Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
KeyFactory keyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("myKind");
Key key = keyFactory.newKey("myKey");
Entity entity = Entity.newBuilder(key)
    .set("name", "Jane Doe")
    .set("age", 40)
    .build();
datastore.put(entity);
```

You can view the [API documentation here](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.0/apidocs/?com/google/cloud/datastore/package-summary.html), and don't forget you need to [setup authentication correctly](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#authentication).